# UISwitch to turn on/off UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios6, uigesturerecognizer, uiswitch

I have the following methods declared in my app, and I want to implement a switch to turn on and off `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in my mapView.

```
- (IBAction)addNewPin:(UISwitch *)sender {

if (sender.on) {

NSLog(@"ON!!");
}

else {

NSLog(@"OFF!!");
}

}


- (IBAction)didPressForPin:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
pa.coordinate = locCoord;
pa.title = @"Test Title!";
[mapView addAnnotation:pa];


NSLog(@"Pressed!!");


}
```

I know that I can add or remove the gesturerecognizer or implement `.enabled = NO`, but I do not know how to implement it in the switch method.

Comment: And how is this question related to "Xcode 4.5"?

Comment: youre 99% there, I'm not sure what it is you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can help assuming you have a `longPressGestureRecognizer` property:

```
@synthesize longPressGestureRecognizer = _longPressGestureRecognizer;

- (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer
{
    if (_longPressGestureRecognizer) {
        return _longPressGestureRecognizer;
    }

    _longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
    return _longPressGestureRecognizer;
}


- (IBAction)toggleAddPinSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    if ([sender isOn]) {
        [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
    } else {
        [self.mapView removeGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just added "_longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
    return _longPressGestureRecognizer;
" to ViewDidLoad in order to work with my touch to location method.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy coding.